# I am trying to increase the count variable using this, but let is creating problem , whereas var works fine

Tags: javascript, this, var, let

I am trying to understand how "this" keyword works and trying to increase the count variable using a function. But If i use let to declare count, count does not increase , but if i use var to declare count it works. I don't know why is this happening.

```
let count = 0;
function increaseCounter() {
  this.count++;
};
increaseCounter()
console.log(count)
```

Answer (score 2):

The `this` keyword in JavaScript refers to the object that is currently executing the code. In the case of a function, the `this` keyword refers to the object that the function is a property of.

In your case, you are trying to increase the value of the count variable by using the `this` keyword inside the `increaseCounter` function. However, the count variable is not a property of any object, so the this keyword inside the function is not referencing the count variable as you'd expect.

`this` has a different context depending where it is being used . Check out [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) and/or  [W3](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_this.asp) for a good explanation.

As far as the `let` vs `var` problem. Each have a different scope. Read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/762011/what-is-the-difference-between-let-and-var) about that.

Comment: Your "W3" link is broken.

Comment: Avoid links to w3schools, they're famous for their horrible explanations - their page on `this` is no exception. Also they are not affiliated with the W3C, so beware the name. Better link [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this).

Answer (score 0):

The function and variable is not in a `class`, which means you do not need to use the `this` keyword. You can omit it and just use `count++;`.

If the function and variable is in a class, then the `this` keyword is necessary.

Since the code is not working for you, that means you are not in a class, and you should use the first option. The `let` keyword does not affect this.

For more information, I recommend checking out [Classes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes), [Let vs. Var](https://sentry.io/answers/difference-between-let-and-var-in-javascript/#:%7E:text=The%20difference%20between%20let%20and,in%20which%20they%27re%20declared.), and [The `this` Keyword](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this)

Answer (score -1):

"var" is global scoped whereas let is function scoped. Thats why when you "var", the "this" which you used inside the function can find property "count" which is available globally.

Comment: Both `var` and `let` can be globally scoped or function-scoped.